# Find number 9 in file - linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find how many times number "9" appears in the result of the draw 
(ignoring the ordinal number and date)

```
65. 11.05.1958 8,17,22,27,31,21
66. 18.05.1958 1,2,8,17,28,54
67. 25.05.1958 7,16,27,33,41,23
68. 01.06.1958 1,20,41,42,43,43
69. 08.06.1952 13,14,25,29,33,47
70. 15.06.1958 17,23,29,39,41,45
71. 22.06.1958 2,14,22,44,48,49
72. 29.06.1958 3,7,13,15,16,47
73. 06.07.1958 10,11,28,38,48,49
74. 13.07.1956 9,16,21,24,27,35
75. 20.07.1958 1,7,17,18,29,32
76. 27.07.1958 19,21,42,25,36,44
77. 03.08.1958 2,4,22,31,32,43
78. 10.08.1958 4,9,16,26,27,46
79. 17.08.1958 34,35,37,38,39,45
80. 24.08.1958 17,21,27,35,41,49
81. 31.08.1958 30,31,32,9,46,49
82. 07.09.1958 10,16,23,26,30,39
83. 14.09.1958 13,16,18,19,30,35
84. 21.09.1958 9,23,26,29,31,42
85. 28.09.1958 12,16,21,28,9,49
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text to search is in a file named `output.txt`:

```
cut <output.txt -d ' ' -f 3 | grep -w 9 | wc -l
```

The `cut` part splits by spaces, taking the third field.

`grep -w` finds `9` as a word, so the for example the line with `10,16,23,26,30,39` won't get picked.

Finally, `wc -l` counts how many lines we have.

Comment: I'd suggest `<output.txt cut ...`, avoiding the use of `cat`. More efficient to give programs a direct handle on the real input file than make them read from a FIFO -- and while it doesn't matter _that_ much for `cut`, some other programs like `sort`, `tail`, `wc`, &c. can be vastly more efficient given a seekable FD, since it lets them parallelize reads, jump straight to the end, test file size without having to actually read file content, etc.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

Use awk to remove the first 2 columns, then use grep -c to find the 9s.  Put a \b around the regex to make sure it doesn't track 19,29,91,92,93,etc.  Assuming your output is coming from `FILENAME`:

`awk '{ print $3 }' FILENAME | grep -c '\b9\b`

Comment: Might also consider having `awk` do the counting itself; it has all the capabilities `grep` has.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { count=0 } $3 ~ /(^|,)9($|,)/ { ++count } END { print(count) }' FILENAME`, f/e.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're probably right but I'm pretty weak with awk.  How would something like that look?  Likely more performant but also uglier.

Comment: See above comment, which includes a working example. :)

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

And just for fun, here is yet another way, this one in Perl:

```
perl -nle '$c+=()=/\b(9)\b/g; END {print $c}' $FILENAME
```

This has the difference that it allows 9 to appear multiple times, and counts them all. Because it uses `/g` (global) and first casts the result to an array `()=`, before adding the number of elements in the array to `$c`.